# What are the reasons for getting the AOBB_STATE_ERROR_COULD_NOT_MOUNT return code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, mount

Working with Android NDK it seems completely random if my build can mount the corresponding obb, created by the jobb tool.
When failing to mount, I get the return code `AOBB_STATE_ERROR_COULD_NOT_MOUNT`.

As this is not very informative, I've found several possible error sources looking at the internet:

- The path to the obb file is not allowed to start with `/` (although the the path returned from nativeActivity starts with a `/`)
- Version mismatches
- Previous versions of the jobb tools encryption was broken, meaning it did not work with password protected obb files
- Due to bugs in Android the permission `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` had to be enabled in SDK version 23
- A localy uploaded obb file might not be mounted if it's name starts with "main"
- Some obbs just don't mount due to a bug in the jobb tool hash key generation (see [Android. ERROR_COULD_NOT_MOUNT while mounting complex ciphered obb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901688/android-error-could-not-mount-while-mounting-complex-ciphered-obb-file))

As I seem to fulfill at least these requirements, does anyone know any more reasons that `AOBB_STATE_ERROR_COULD_NOT_MOUNT` is return (ie error code 21)?

Comment: Okay, as a final recommendation if anyone is even thinking about using obbs, do not use obb's at all, use a zip archive and incorporate libzip in your ndk application :)